# Как сделать так чтобы в текстовый файл записывался протокол программы?

Tags: c++, c++builder

Программа решает задачу синхронизации потоков "читатель-писатель" с использование критических секций. Как сделать так чтобы по ходу работы программы в текстовый файл писался протокол с указанием времени (чч:мм:сс) + что происходит (читатель читает, писатель пишет) - т.е. то что я сейчас пишу в Memo1.

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <vcl.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "Unit1.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
using namespace std;
DWORD WINAPI  ThreadRead(LPVOID);
DWORD WINAPI  ThreadWrite(LPVOID);
CRITICAL_SECTION cs; //критическая секция
vector <HANDLE> writers;//массив писателей
vector <HANDLE> readers;//массив читателей
vector <string> queue1;//очередь заданий 1
vector <string> queue2;//очередь заданий 2
int reader_count = 0;//количество читателей
int writer_count = 0;//количество писателей
int queue1_length = 0;//количество заданий в первой очереди
int queue2_length = 0;//количество заданий во второй очереди
TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DWORD WINAPI ThreadRead(LPVOID Param){ //обработка потока "Читатель"
   int index = *(int*)Param;
   while(Form1->CheckBox1->Checked == false)
   {
      if (queue1_length > queue2_length && queue1_length > 0)
      {
         Form1->Memo1->Lines->Add(IntToStr(index) + "-ый читатель обработал строку: " + queue1.begin()->c_str());
         queue1.erase(queue1.begin());
         queue1_length--;
         Form1->Edit3->Text = IntToStr(queue1_length); //показать количество заданий в первой очереди
      }
      else if(queue2_length > 0)
      {
         Form1->Memo1->Lines->Add(IntToStr(index) + "-ый читатель обработал строку: " + queue2.begin()->c_str());
         queue2.erase(queue2.begin());
         queue2_length--;
         Form1->Edit4->Text = IntToStr(queue2_length); //показать количество заданий во второй очереди
      }
      Sleep(1000); //читатель "засыпает"
   }
}

DWORD WINAPI ThreadWrite(LPVOID Param){//обработка потока "Писатель"
/*писатель должен иметь монопольный доступ к разделаемому ресурсу
поэтому он помещается в критическую секцию*/
   int index = *(int*)Param;
   while(Form1->CheckBox1->Checked == false){
      EnterCriticalSection(&cs); //входим в критическую секцию
      ostringstream ss;
      ss << index;
      if(queue1_length < queue2_length)
      {
         string str = ss.str() + "-ый писатель записал задание в очередь №1";
         queue1.push_back(str); //добавляем задание в конец очереди №1
         queue1_length++; //увеличиваем счетчик заданий
         Form1->Edit3->Text = IntToStr(queue1_length);
      }
      else{
         string str = ss.str() + "-ый писатель записал задание в очередь №2";
         queue2.push_back(str); //добавляем задание в конец очереди №2
         queue2_length++; //увеличиваем счетчик заданий
         Form1->Edit4->Text = IntToStr(queue2_length);
      }
      LeaveCriticalSection(&cs); //покидаем критическую секцию
      Sleep(2000); //писатель "засыпает"
   }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
        : TForm(Owner)
{
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
/*Обработчик кнопки "Добавить читателя*/
void __fastcall TForm1::BitBtn1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
   reader_count++;
   Form1->Edit1->Text = IntToStr(reader_count);
   //вставляем создаваемый поток "читатель" в массив читателей
   readers.push_back(CreateThread(NULL,0,ThreadRead,&reader_count,0,NULL));
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
/*Обработчик кнопки "Удалить читателя*/
void __fastcall TForm1::BitBtn2Click(TObject *Sender)
{
   reader_count--;
   Form1->Edit1->Text = IntToStr(reader_count);
   TerminateThread(readers.back(),0);
   readers.pop_back();
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
/*Обработчик кнопки "Добавить писателя*/
void __fastcall TForm1::BitBtn3Click(TObject *Sender)
{
 writer_count++;
   Form1->Edit2->Text = IntToStr(writer_count);
   //вставляем создаваемый поток "писатель" в массив писателей
   writers.push_back(CreateThread(NULL,0,ThreadWrite,&writer_count,0,NULL));

}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
/*Обработчик кнопки "Удалить писателя*/
void __fastcall TForm1::BitBtn4Click(TObject *Sender)
{
   writer_count--;
   Form1->Edit2->Text = IntToStr(writer_count);
   TerminateThread(writers.back(),0);
   writers.pop_back();
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TForm1::FormCreate(TObject *Sender)
{
   //при запуске формы происходит инициализация критической секции
   InitializeCriticalSection(&cs);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TForm1::FormClose(TObject *Sender, TCloseAction &Action)
{
   //при закрытии формы удаляется критическая секция
   DeleteCriticalSection(&cs);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Может ручками?)

Comment: Протокол нужен по заданию.

Comment: Ну, берете и открываете файл. Записываете время и сообщение. Закрываете при выходе.

Comment: а с помощью какой функции записывать время?

Comment: [а с помощью какой функции записывать время?] Получать время с помощью time(), конвертировать время в строку с помощью localtime() и asctime(), а записывать строку в файл как любую строку записываете.